# How to configure a traffic route from VM1 through Host to VM2

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, routing

I'm using Virtualbox for VM's Ubuntu 20.04.
My task is to configure the network in such a way that traffic from VM1 passes through Host (Windows 10) and then to VM2, as well as in the opposite direction.

For interfaces I use Virtualbox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter.
As an example, the task looks like this:
VM1-Ub-(192.168.3.4) <-> Host-Win-(192.168.3.3) <-> VM1-Ub-(192.168.3.5)

It is necessary through Host-Win.

I tried:

1. VM1: `ip route add 192.168.3.4/24 via 192.168.3.3`
2. Host: `route add 192.168.3.4 mask 255.255.255.255 192.168.3.5`
3. VM2: `ip route add 192.168.3.5/24 via 192.168.3.3`

And other methods.

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: I tried:
1. VM1 ip route add 192.168.3.4/24 via 192.168.3.3
2. Host route add 192.168.3.4 mask 255.255.255.255 192.168.3.5
3. VM2 ip route add 192.168.3.5/24 via 192.168.3.3
And other methods, but I still haven’t found a working solution.

Comment: Your host routes lack a rule in the other direction. Also, you should give all rules a low metric (just in case). Did you try in the VMs to ping the host and each other, and what are the results. Please [Edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1818032/edit) your question to add information, rather than using comments.

Comment: Why would you route through the host instead of going directly to VM2? Your described route is unrealistic.

Answer (score 0):

> It is necessary through Host-Win

In that case, you *preferably* shouldn't have the VMs on the same subnet. When they're in the same subnet, they will "know" that they can reach each other directly (via VirtualBox's internal vSwitch) and will not try to send packets through any gateway.

(Technically traffic *does* pass through the host...

The host should have *two* Host-Only Adapters, configured for different subnets, with VM1 connected to one and VM2 to the other, and each VM should have the host's IP address as a gateway (either default gateway, or just a gateway to the "opposite" subnet).

That being said, it's still doable when they're in the same subnet, but you will have to manually override the "local subnet" routes that the VMs will have – e.g. by deleting them, or by configuring the netmask as /32 (255.255.255.255) to prevent a direct route from being added in the first place.

> I tried:
>
> 1. VM1: ip route add 192.168.3.4/24 via 192.168.3.3
> 2. Host: route add 192.168.3.4 mask 255.255.255.255 192.168.3.5
> 3. VM2: ip route add 192.168.3.5/24 via 192.168.3.3

For 1 and 3, if you're trying to add a route for a single host, then the netmask needs to be /32 (kind of like what you did in route 2 with 255.255.255.255). The network's actual size does not need to be specified.

(Routes are for a host *or* a network – not for "a host in a network"; using /24 just creates a "192.168.3.0/24" route, discarding all the bits that don't fit in the /24.)

Route 2 overall does not make any sense. You got the 255.255.255.255 correct, but the destination and gateway, in combination, do not match your topology at all – VM1 is not behind VM2.